# File available but giving 404 in wordpress

Tags: errors, redirect, customization

Hey,
im not sure why but php files other then wordpress either redirects to homepage or gives a 404. 
for example i have a timthumb.php in directory /js/

it was working fine and generating thumnails for me.. but it started to give 404 on even running the direct url.

You can take a look here : www.designzzz.com/js/ you will see timthumb.php available, but on clicking or running that file it gives 404 :( .

Help is appreciated :)

cheers

Ayaz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the permissions on the JS folder against the folders for the rest of the site.

Comment: k my bad i guess.. tahts really odd all folders have 755 why does it had 777 :( . thx fixed :)

Comment: Global permissions are usually the answer when your server is configured to run as `nobody`. This is what causes trouble for a lot of users, usually with the `uploads` folder. Some argue `nobody` is a security `improvement`, others argue that the requirements it induces create exactly the opposite - http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#The_dangers_of_777